# The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Geolocation

Tags: c#, asp.net, geolocation

i can find more errors with the same heading. but did not give the solution of mine. i am try to create small application to get the user location , and reverse it. all are good working fine. When i tested with my pc and publish it was working fine and no errors at all. Now i try to put it in another pc(IIS) trying to access from my pc application running perfect but when it reach to read the location its throwing the above error. i did some google most of them are saying authentication problem,or time out issue. but it was in my pc work perfect even in(IIS), i try to access from other laptop and all work good.

```html
Server Error in '/' Application.
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +1695
   System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy) +105
   System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn) +86
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrlDelegate(Object xmlResolver) +71
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData) +0
   System.Threading.CompressedStack.Run(CompressedStack compressedStack, ContextCallback callback, Object state) +112
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenUrl() +396
   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read() +296
   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) +158
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) +134
   System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename) +146
   WiseDistribution.Settings.usrProfile.getlocationname() in D:\Projects\UserLocation\Settings\usrProfile.aspx.cs:190
   WiseDistribution.Settings.usrProfile.imgUpdate_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) in D:\Projects\UserLocation\Settings\usrProfile.aspx.cs:152
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.OnClick(ImageClickEventArgs e) +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +186
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1665
```

this is error i am getting.

my config file is.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>   
   Connection string
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
 <add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'" />
    <add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}'" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" />
    </authentication>
    <profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
  </system.web>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Really no idea where is the problem. All location tracing button click return the same error. And same time if i try to debug(run visual studio) from my pc i am not getting any error, even i use the remote server database and webconfig file.

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=abcdeff&callback=myMap"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var longitude = $('#longitude');
            var latitude = $('#latitude');
            var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (p) {
                    console.log(longitude);
                    longitude.text(p.coords.longitude);
                    latitude.text(p.coords.latitude);
                    document.getElementById(hiddenControl).value=p.coords.latitude + "," + p.coords.longitude;
                    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
                 //   alert(p.coords.latitude);
                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: LatLng,
                        zoom: 20,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: LatLng,
                        map: map,
                        title: "<div style = 'height:60px;width:200px'><b>Your location:</b><br />Latitude: " + p.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + p.coords.longitude,

                    });
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                        infoWindow.setContent(marker.title);
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                });
            } else {
                alert('Location feature is not supported in this browser.');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

this is html side javascript code

```html
 public void getlocationname()
        {
            //  string coordinate = latitude.InnerText + "," + longitude.InnerText; // "32.797821,-96.781720"; 
            string coordinate = inpHide.Value;
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            //  xDoc.Load("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" + coordinate);
            xDoc.Load("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=abcdff&callback&latlng=" + coordinate + "&sensor=false");
            XmlNodeList xNodelst = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("result");
            XmlNode xNode = xNodelst.Item(0);
            string FullAddress = xNode.SelectSingleNode("formatted_address").InnerText;
            string Number = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[1]/long_name").InnerText;
            string Street = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[2]/long_name").InnerText;
            string Village = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[3]/long_name").InnerText;
            string Area = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[4]/long_name").InnerText;
            string County = xNode.SelectSingleNode("address_component[5]/long_name").InnerText;

            locationName = FullAddress;
        }
```

code behind to get location name(for saving the data)

Comment: Are you calling any third party api for geolocation? Is the api call over https? And do how do you pass input parameters using json or xml?

Comment: google api, only http. i dont get the input parameter. but i am not passing any parameter. Its like once the user click the button it will capture the location of the user. using google api and save to database nothing special.

Comment: Can you share the getlocationname method code?

Comment: updated with the code. If i publish to normal windows 10 pc its working , but not with server. i tried just now with windows 10 other pc it is working fine.

Comment: Try url encoding the coordinate querystring parameter. 
`xDoc.Load("https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?key=abcdff&callback&latlng=" + HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode(coordinate) + "&sensor=false");`

Comment: showing me error an object reference is required for non-static field.

Comment: Try using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`

Comment: HttpUtility.UrlEncode  it accept but its return same error.i mean even i put that in the string , same effect